# CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION is pointing to the old GCC version

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I have upgraded my GCC using:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 70 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
```

Running any of these commands:

```
$ gcc --version
$ g++ --version
$ c++ --version
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
$ /usr/bin/g++ --version
$ /usr/bin/c++ --version
```

would show `(Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04) 8.1.0` confirming that version `8.1` has been installed.

When running `./configure` on `cmake-3.12.1` I downloaded from its website I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
```

**However** when trying to `make` my actual project:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (message):
  GCC version must be at least 7.1! 5.4.0
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    # require at least gcc 7.1
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 7.1)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "GCC version must be at least 7.1!  " ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION})
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Did you delete any old cmake cache files first?

Comment: Have you clear the CMake cache (file `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory) of your project after updating the compiler?

Comment: There are no CMakeCache.txt file in the project's directory.

Comment: *in the build directory*! not project directory

Comment: @hellow what's build directory?  `$ locate CMakeCache.txt $/home/user/.go/native/x86_64-linux-gnu/protobuf/CMakeCache.txt
$/home/user/.go/native/x86_64-linux-gnu/rocksdb/CMakeCache.txt`

Comment: @d9ngle assuming that you're doing an out-of-source build, it's the directory of your choice, from where you issue the `cmake [path-to-source-dir]` command.

Comment: Hmm, after reading your question again, why are you running `./configure`? Aren't you supposed to run `cmake ..` or similar?

Comment: @hellow `./configure` is used to install the last version of `cmake` (because my project needed a higher version).

Comment: As you may notice, your question cannot be answered very easily, because it lacks some important information. What is in your configure file? How do you invoke cmake? Are there any steps before or after the `configure`/`make`? Please edit your question regardinly

Comment: @hellow Oops. There is actually a directory called `build` with `CMakeCache.txt` inside it. It's solved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Shawn, Tsyvarev and hellow have mentioned in the comments, this problem is caused by CMake cache file which was located inside `/build/`. Deleting the file solved the issue.